# SQL server joining more than one table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have 6 tables that contains students information. All of them share the same column names, but with different data. So, the question is how to make a report of student demographics by semester by Academic College covering a six year period? Would you use left joins for this type of question? I tried to use inner join but it did not work. Actually, that's what I did:

```
SELECT DOB, SEX, RACE, MAJORCOLLEGE

FROM MasterFile2006

Join MasterFile2007 ON MasterFile2006.HOMEID = MasterFile2007.HOMEID

Join MasterFile2008 ON MasterFile2006.HOMEID = MasterFile2008.HOMEID

Join MasterFile2009 ON MasterFile2006.HOMEID = MasterFile2009.HOMEID

Join MasterFile2010 ON MasterFile2006.HOMEID = MasterFile2010.HOMEID

Join MasterFile2011 ON MasterFile2006.HOMEID = MasterFile2011.HOMEID
```

I would really appreciate your help!!

Comment: Joins are for "joining" related data together usually from multiple tables with differing fields (excepting on or more keys for the ON phrase.) See Wheats answer.

Comment: Oh yeah sorry, I was typing before then

Comment: you might want to add the name of the file or just year as a separate field in solution of @MitchWheat

Comment: Updated and added: good suggestion.

Answer (score 4):

Use a `UNION`:

```
SELECT DOB, SEX, RACE, MAJORCOLLEGE, '2006' as [Year] FROM MasterFile2006
UNION ALL
SELECT DOB, SEX, RACE, MAJORCOLLEGE, '2007' as [Year] FROM MasterFile2007
UNION ALL
SELECT DOB, SEX, RACE, MAJORCOLLEGE, '2008' as [Year] FROM MasterFile2008
UNION ALL
SELECT DOB, SEX, RACE, MAJORCOLLEGE, '2009' as [Year] FROM MasterFile2009
UNION ALL
SELECT DOB, SEX, RACE, MAJORCOLLEGE, '2010' as [Year] FROM MasterFile2010
UNION ALL
SELECT DOB, SEX, RACE, MAJORCOLLEGE, '2011' as [Year] FROM MasterFile2011
```

Note: `UNION ALL` does not discard duplicates (and there should not be any), `UNION` performs a `DISTINCT` and discards duplicate rows.

Answer (score 1):

> You need to use `UNION ALL` or `UNION`. Use `UNION` if you need `DISTINCT` records.

```
SELECT DOB, SEX, RACE, MAJORCOLLEGE FROM MasterFile2006
UNION
SELECT DOB, SEX, RACE, MAJORCOLLEGE FROM MasterFile2007
UNION
SELECT DOB, SEX, RACE, MAJORCOLLEGE FROM MasterFile2008
UNION
SELECT DOB, SEX, RACE, MAJORCOLLEGE FROM MasterFile2009
UNION
SELECT DOB, SEX, RACE, MAJORCOLLEGE FROM MasterFile2010
UNION
SELECT DOB, SEX, RACE, MAJORCOLLEGE FROM MasterFile2011
```

Comment: @Praveen Nambiar: 5 minutes after seems a bit late.

Comment: @MitchWheat +1 to you also sir.